# Drupal view - Cross compatibility with IE 11 text align issue

Tags: html, css, drupal, drupal-7

My community page (http://www.workbooks.com/help.html) looks great in Chrome but in IE it looks cruddy. See:

[image: Community image]

This is a view created in Drupal made up of four blocks. So it's not as easy as creating a css id for each paragraph and applying top padding.

**I need to lower the text so it doesn't sit ontop of the images.**

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: You need to write CSS rule specifically for IE

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: To fix css on IE, either you need to write separate css file or add IE specific css rules in current css file